# Cucumber Datatable, Can there be a list inside datatable cell?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

Given this example:
I have a list of books that I want to add to the system. Each book is mandatory to have book name and a variable number of authors. When writing a data table for my example I did the following:

```
| book name | author name a| author name b | author name c|
| book 1    | author 1     |               |              |
| book 2    | author 2.1   | author 2.2    |              |
```

This worked fine here, but is there a better way to approach the same problem. Another scenario for an example where the input is a variable list of 3 to 5 elements. It doesn't **feel** right to do the following:

```
|element a | element b| element c | element d| element e|
```

Is there a support for a comma separated list inside a cell, something such as (given that this didn't work for me):

```
|book | authors   |
| b1  | a1, a2, a3|
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad way to use Cucumber. If you want to add a book with multiple authors create a step for that

```
When I add a book with multiple authors
```

rather than put stuff in a table.

In general using tables in features is not the way to go. The bigger and more complex the table the further you are getting away from how cucumber was designed to be used.